# @quasar/extras/mdi-v4 jest unit testing failing on Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: jestjs, quasar

I am using the new SVG images. I have created a test for a header that contains a logo, name mdiMenu.

import { mdiMenu } from '@quasar/extras/mdi-v4'
But everything I am running the test: I always get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      29 | 
      30 | <script>
    > 31 | import { mdiMenu } from '@quasar/extras/mdi-v4'
Do somebody else have encounter this problem and how can I solve this?

This is the rest of the error message:

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.        

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    C:\Users\YohnCheung\work\bitBucket\central-station\node_modules\@quasar\extras\mdi-v4\index.js:3
    export const mdiAbTesting = 'M4 2A2 2 0 0 0 2 4V12H4V8H6V12H8V4A2 2 0 0 0 6 2H4M4 4H6V6H4M22 15.5V14A2 2 0 0 0 20 12H16V22H20A2 2 0 0 0 22 20V18.5A1.54 1.54 0 0 0 20.5 17A1.54 1.54 0 0 0 22 15.5M20 20H18V18H20V20M20 16H18V14H20M5.79 21.61L4.21 20.39L18.21 2.39L19.79 3.61Z'
    ^^^^^^
```

Question was taken from:

https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/5459/quasar-extras-mdi-v4-jest-unit-testing-failing
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/quasar-extras-mdi-v4-jest-unit-testing-failing/89973

Answer (score 0):

Correct transformation need to be set.
So you need to configure jest.config.js correctly

```
 ...
 transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': require.resolve('babel-jest'),
 },
 ...
```

My jest config is extending preset

```
preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel',
```

which already includes this transform, but also sets not to transform pacages from node_modules

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
```

reference: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/default/jest-preset.js

therefore in my config I have changed pattern to

```
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(quasar|quasar/*|@quasar|@quasar/*))'],
```

so it ignores all packages but quasar's

Hope this answer will help someone :)